# Easy way to host a debian update repository

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt-get

I have a project where I create a single .deb file, which should be installed by a linux client. For this I would like to use `apt-get install mypackage`.

Being quite new to this area, I am now looking for the most simple way of hosting my own debian update repository, which will only have to contain mypackage.deb.

I quickly looked at [mini-dinstall](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/mini-dinstall.1.html) which looked promising, but they seem to work with `.changes`, rather than `.deb` packages. So I am not sure if this is what I need.

So summarized the workflow should look something like this:

1. I create the debian package `mypackage.deb`
2. I tell some daemon to update the update repository: `fancy-update-daemon add mypackage.deb`
3. The client is able to install or update using standard apt commands: `apt-get install mypackage`

Thanks for your help

Comment: askubuntu.com is the best place for this question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The really simple way of creating a repository is to create a "trivial" repository instead of an "automatic" repository.  You can do this with the "dpkg-scanpackages" command in the dpkg-dev package.

```
$ mkdir repository
$ cp foo.deb repository
$ dpkg-scanpackages repository /dev/null | gzip -9c > repository/Packages.gz
```

Then in your sources.list, instead of having something like:

```
deb http://wherever/repository suite component
```

You leave off the suite and component and just have:

```
deb http://wherever/repository
```

For more info (like the difference between a trivial and automatic repository) see [The repository HOWTO](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/repository-howto/repository-howto) (for something this simple, you can ignore the fact that this documentation calls itself "obsolete")

Comment: Thanks very much. This looks promising. I guess I could also manage different versions of the same package with this mechanism.

I'll definitely try it out.

Comment: dpkg-scanpackage won't put multiple versions of the same package into the same Packages file, if that is what you mean.  If you give it a directory with multiple versions of the same package, you'll only end up with the newest in the Packages.gz

Comment: @stew in recent versions, you can give dpkg-scanpackage the `-m` switch to add multiple versions of the same package to Packages.

Comment: I get `E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/...` I created a new answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Create Packages.gz:

```
@server> cd debian-repo
@server> dpkg-scanpackages ./ /dev/null | gzip > Packages.gz
```

Create new file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/my-server.list (at client)

```
deb http://my-server/debian-repo ./
```

Now get the list of available packages and install `foo`.

```
@client> apt-get update
@client> apt-get install foo
```

Comment: For me, apt would not install the package because the repository was untrusted. I fixed it by using `deb [trusted=yes] http://my-server/debian-repo ./`.

Answer (score 0):

[`.changes`](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-debianchangesfiles) files are generated while building a debian package. A `.changes` file is not a package by itself: it contains information about the build ([including `.deb`s that were generated](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Binary)).

While I haven't used `mini-dinstall`, it seems like the right way to go. It should use the `.deb` files that were generated during the build and upload them correctly.